# Define algebra over GF4

Tags: haskell

How to define the algebraic operations over finite field power 4 (GF4) in Haskell?

I have numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3

And the operators could look like this:

```
(+) x y = (x + y) `mod` 4
(*) 0 y = 0
(*) 1 y = y
(*) x 0 = 0
(*) x 1 = x
(*) 2 2 = 3
(*) 3 3 = 2
(*) 2 3 = 1
(*) 3 2 = 1
```

Note: (*) is not multiple mod 4!

I want to get something like this:

```
3 * 2 :: GF4 == 1 :: GF4
```

I write:

```
class GF4 x where
  (+), (*) :: x -> x -> x

instance GF4 where
  0 + 0 = 0
  ...
  2 * 3 = 1
  ...
```

But unsuccessfully! How to write an implement of this operators by type class or type?

Comment: I think `GF4` here should *not* be a typclass, but a type. You can make it an instance of `Num` and then define `(+)`, `(-)`, `(*)`, etc. over GF4.

Comment: Don't define a `class` unless you foresee _more than one_ `instance`s for it. In your case, use instead something like `data GF4 = A0 | A1 | A2 | A3` and provide it with a suitable `instance Num GF4`.

Comment: I think it's a bit too advanced for you right now, but if this is something you have long-term interest in, you may want to check out the [galois-field](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/galois-field) package once you've got a bit more Haskell expertise.

Comment: If you want to have a field you must not use addition mod 4, but xor as addition, see chi's comment to Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
data GF4 = GF4_0 | GF4_1 | GF4_2 | GF4_3
    deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, {- Ord, maybe? -} Read, Show)

instance Num GF4 where
    -- A small trick to avoid having to write all the cases by hand:
    -- reuse the `Num Int` instance and use the `Enum GF4` instance to
    -- convert back and forth.

    -- BUT note that, though this was the original question's spec for
    -- (+), this is not how addition in GF4 is usually defined. Thanks
    -- to chi for pointing it out. Presumably the definition for x - y
    -- below also needs to be updated; perhaps defining negate instead
    -- would involve less repetition.
    x + y = toEnum ((fromEnum x + fromEnum y) `mod` 4)

    GF4_0 * y = 0
    GF4_1 * y = y
    GF4_2 * GF4_2 = GF4_3
    -- etc.

    -- and a couple other bookkeeping functions; see :info Num or the haddocks
    x - y = toEnum ((fromEnum x - fromEnum y) `mod` 4)
    fromInteger n = toEnum (fromInteger (n `mod` 4))
    abs = id
    signum = toEnum . signum . fromEnum
```

Now you can try it out in ghci:

```
> (3 * 2 :: GF4) == (1 :: GF4)
True
```

Another option that makes the `Num` instance less tedious is to explicitly represent it as a polynomial with mod-2 coefficients. I'll pull a silly trick I've pulled a few times before to treat `Bool` as mod-2 numbers (with `False` representing 0 and `True` representing 1):

```
instance Num Bool where
    (+) = (/=)
    (*) = (&&)
    negate = not
    abs = id
    signum = id
    fromInteger = odd
```

(An aside for the Haskell experts: if the orphan instance makes you queasy, feel free to define `data Bit = O | I` and write out the `Num` instance a bit more explicitly.)

Now we define `GF4` to have two fields ("fields" in the programming sense, not the number theory sense):

```
data GF4 = Bool :×+ Bool deriving (Eq, {- Ord, maybe? -} Read, Show)
```

The `×+` is supposed to be a bit of a visual pun: we'll represent *ax + b* as `a:×+b`. Now the (corrected) `Num` instance looks quite a bit more ordered:

```
instance Num GF4 where
    (a:×+b) + (a':×+b') = (a + a'):×+(b + b')
    (a:×+b) * (a':×+b') = (a*a' + a*b' + b*a'):×+(a*a' + b*b')
    negate = id
    abs = id
    signum (a:×+b) = 0:×+(a*b)
    fromInteger n = 0:×+fromInteger n

x :: GF4
x = 1:×+0
```

Unlike the previous instance, not all inhabitants of this `GF4` are available as literal numbers -- only the constant polynomials. So we define an extra value, `x`, to give access to the non-constant polynomials. (Or you can use the constructor directly.) Now we can try out your example in ghci; what you call `2` I call `x`, and what you call `3` I call `x+1`.

```
> (x+1) * x == 1
True
```

Comment: I believe that the definition of `(+)` exploiting `mod` as you did (and as the OP posted in their question) is wrong. The GF4 field has characteristic two, so we must have `1+1==0`. Addition in GF4 is not addition modulo 4.

Comment: @chi Absolutely correct. I'm going to keep the computational content of my example code as close as possible to the original question, to make it easier to spot the parallels, but I'll add a comment pointing out that this is not the standard addition.

Comment: @chi I decided to put a correct instance in after all -- but with a slightly better representation for that.

Answer (score 2):

As @WillemVanOnsem says in the comments, `GF4` should be a data type, rather than a typeclass. Despite the name, they are totally different things! A typeclass is a collection of functions which are general enough that they can have similar implementations for multiple different types; a data type is nearly the reverse, in that it defines a totally new type which the users may use as they wish.

So how do you define `GF4` as a data type? The ‘simplest’ way (for one definition of ‘simplest’) is to simply define it as a wrapper around `Int`:

```
newtype GF4 = GF4 Int
```

(Quick note: in case you haven’t run into them before, `newtype`s are a special kind of data type; they are used when you want to give a new name to another type by wrapping it. See e.g. [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#the-newtype-keyword) for the difference between `newtype`s and `data`s.)

Now, note that `(+)` and `(*)` are members of the `Num` typeclass — this makes sense, since you can implement those functions for a wide range of types — so now you can write a `Num` instance:

```
instance Num GF4 where
    (+) (GF4 x) (GF4 y) = GF4 ((x + y) `mod` 4)
    (*) (GF4 0) (GF4 y) = GF4 0
    (*) (GF4 1) (GF4 y) = GF4 y
    -- and so on and so forth

    -- but Num also has some other functions; let’s implement those too

    negate (GF 0) = GF 0
    negate (GF 1) = (GF 3)
    negate (GF 2) = GF 2
    -- note that a ‘negate’ implementation automatically gives you (-) as well

    abs x = x
    signum x = x

    -- this is an unsafe function — usually you’d avoid them, but it’s the
    -- only way to implement this one
    fromInteger x = if 0 <= x && x < 4 then GF (fromInteger x) else error "value out of bounds!"
```

Then, you can export the name of the type `GF4`, but not the constructor `GF4 :: Int -> GF4`; thus outside people can use your type, but cannot construct invalid values like `GF4 30`.

Yet there is a better way. Note that `GF4` only has four values — so it’s totally feasible to define this as an enumeration:

```
data GF4 = GF0 | GF1 | GF2 | GF3
```

This way, you can export everything, and still have it impossible by design to construct invalid values. This is considered good practice in Haskell; for this reason alone, I would use this definition rather than the `newtype` one. The implementation of `Num` is very similar to that given above; for this reason I won’t write the whole thing out again, but you should be able to easily figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a type in our instance declaration. E.g.

```
instance GF4 Int where
  0 + 0 = 0
  2 * 3 = 1
```

To use it you still need to hide `(+)` and `(*)` from `Prelude`:

```
import Prelude hiding ((*), (+))
```

Now you can start using your `GF4` instance:

```
one :: Int
one = 2 * 3
```